# What are some ways to have config files in C#?

Tags: c#

I love the way Python does it, such that you can have a readable config file within a .py file itself.

This config file is meant for developers only so it doesn't have to be user friendly. What methods can I use to store verbose information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In .NET we use separate .config files. Data can be read with the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

in .NET its even easier!
using system.configuration to read sections from app.config file.

msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

simple example:
http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/21709-Reading-value-from-App-Config-C-Windows.aspx

Hec

Answer (score 0):

I think the article [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx) in the MSDN is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to external config files, you could use a DSL in C# to configure the system, much like is common in things like ASP.NET MVC and/or StructureMap registration.

Of course, if you like the python approach you could run a py script via [IronPython](http://www.ironpython.com/) to configure your system with a bit less xml. This would avoid the need to recompile, while allowing a code-based config script.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the standard way, but you *can* use the IronPython interpreter and have a readable .py config file in .NET, too. The advantage over normal XML-configuration files is that a IronPython config file can contain any code, so it can do things like e.g. loop over all files or contain if-else clauses to use different configuration options depending on e.g. the operating system version.